# Print text of regex'd/replaced element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup and python and I am trying to get the text of a traversed td like below:

```
<tr> 
                  <td class="labelplain">&nbsp;Long Title</td>
                  <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr> 
                        <td class="labelplain">RESOLUTION CALLING FOR AN INVESTIGATION, IN AID OF LEGISLATION, ON THE FREQUENT CHANGES IN THE PHILIPPINE
BANK NOTES AND COINS INITIATED BY THE BANGKO SENTRAL NG PILIPINAS (BSP)</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
```

The thing is I am able to traverse getting this: "RESOLUTION CALLING FOR AN INVESTIGATION, IN AID OF LEGISLATION, ON THE FREQUENT CHANGES IN THE PHILIPPINE
BANK NOTES AND COINS INITIATED BY THE BANGKO SENTRAL NG PILIPINAS (BSP)" with the following below:
long_title = soup.find('td', text = re.compile('Long Title'), attrs={'class': 'labelplain'}).find_next('td')
long_title_text = long_title.text.strip()

But the problem is that there are \r\n in some of the tds like the one above. Notice "PHILIPPINE BANK NOTES", PHILIPPINE is on the first line, newline then BANK NOTES AND COINS.
I am able to replace the newline adding: string = str(long_title).replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ' ')

```
    long_title = soup.find('td', text = re.compile('Long Title'), attrs={'class': 'labelplain'}).find_next('td')            
    string = str(long_title).replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ' ')
    long_title_text = string.text.strip()
```

But the problem is I am getting error below when I print or echo long_title_text by using text.strip():

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

What should be the correct way to address this? I've tried only ".text" but to no avail.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I can actually do the replacement in the text stripped (.text.strip()) variable like so:

```
    long_title = soup.find('td', text = re.compile('Long Title'), attrs={'class': 'labelplain'}).find_next('td')
    long_title_text = long_title.text.strip()
    string = str(long_title_text).replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ' ')
    print (string)
```

And then I get the innertext of text of the html tag that I am interested with. Thanks for looking!